# Can Ice melt in terraria 1.2?

Tags: terraria

Let's face it, a lot of us love building nice water features in our homes when it comes to sandbox games like terraria and minecraft (especially me).

I was planning out a feature to build with water and pumps and stuff, when it occurred to me that Ice is actually frozen water.  I don't think I need to elaborate too hard on the question : can you melt Ice in terraria 1.2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, ice and snow blocks don't care about temperature.

[image: Lava being contained by ice and snow]

Comment: ah damn. screw logic and what a pity :P back to buckets and pumps and stuff

Comment: on the other hand, at least I won't have to worry about furnaces and torches melting the ice

Comment: That picture...I think it says it all.